# Find all calls to all web reference methods in the solution (for one web reference)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, web-reference, find-all-references

In Visual Studio 2012, is there a fast way to find **all** specific lines in my entire solution where **any** call is being made to **any** method that exists within one specific web reference?

I am not looking for just one specific method, my web reference has a large number of methods in it, and I want to find them all.

Or is the best way to go about this to just look for all instantiations of any required object(s) I am creating prior to to calling those web methods, and then narrow it down from there?

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper "Find Usages Advanced", then setting "Usages of Members" will find all usages of the members of the web reference proxy type.

Comment: Nice! Now I just need to get ReSharper. :)

Comment: ReSharper is one of the very few tools I can't live without - I pay out of pocket for my license, just to make certain that I always have it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do some serious code parsing with a custom addin, I'm afraid all you have left is good'ol Ctrl-F.

If you got a particular naming pattern for web methods then regular expressions search might help you too (still Ctrl-F).

Probably not the answer you'd want, but that's that. :p

Answer (score 0):

Probably Resharper can help in your task:

[Find Usage feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Finding_Usages__Finding_Usages_of_a_Symbol.html) can find all reference of a simbol, from a method to a class reference

Answer (score 0):

Delete the web reference, compile, and see what fails : )